# Adding Facebook plugin comments for dynamic products

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i want to add facebook plugin comments box for each item i have in my database to show it in the item page . and want also the created item has facebook plugin comments.

if anyone know how please share it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this response is coming rather late, but once you have an app ID from Facebook, add a simple meta tag to your master page, template page, etc.:

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="..." />`

and then add the comments plugin to your items page template:

`<fb:comments id="comments-box" href="..." num_posts="5"></fb:comments>`

You then need to set the `href="..."` value to the unique URL of each item page. If you're using Razor syntax, it could be as simple as `href="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri"` so long as you can guarantee that for each page, the URL is always exactly the same, i.e., any variation is query string parameters, etc. could have unwanted/unexpected results.

Comment: What am i supposed to add in `meta` tag `content`? as you just wrote `...`

Comment: Your app id provided by Facebook. It's unique to every app which is why I didn't include one. You can find it in the properties of your Facebook app within the developer's site.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include the comments plugin on each page without doing anything special, documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/, there's also a special fb:comments-count tag you can use to output the number of comments for a given URL

Comment: so you tell me that i should create application id for each item manually . Is any way to create it problematically or using API of facebook to create it when creating new item?

Comment: No, you create a single app ID for your site, and each product's page uses its own comments plugin, all linked to the same app ID for analytics and comment moderation purposes